# How to convert $\cos4\theta$ into $\cos3\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

How do i show that:

$\cos 4θ = − \cos 3θ$ for each of the values θ = $\frac{\pi}7, \frac{3{\pi}}7, \frac{5{\pi}}7, \pi.$

How is $\cos4\theta$ related to $\cos3\theta$?

Can someone please explain..

Comment: $\cos x =-\cos (\pi - x)$, why?

Answer (score 2):

$$4\frac{\pi}{7}+3\frac{\pi}{7}=\pi$$ 
$$4\frac{3\pi}{7}+3\frac{3\pi}{7}=3\pi$$ 
etc. So for each of these given angles $\theta$, $4\theta+3\theta$ is an odd multiple of $\pi$. That means the two angles $4\theta$ and $3\theta$ are represented by points on the unit circle that are mirror images with respect to the vertical axis. And that means $4\theta$ and $3\theta$ have opposite cosines.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos 4 \theta = - \cos 3\theta $.

$\Rightarrow \cos4\theta + \cos 3 \theta = 0$.

$\Rightarrow 2\cos\left(\frac{7\theta }{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = 0$.

It boils down to the zero-product rule.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos4\theta=-\cos3\theta=\cos(\pi-3\theta)$$

$$\Rightarrow4\theta=\pm(\pi-3\theta)+n.2\pi, n\in\Bbb Z$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Use the appropriate so-called sum-to-product formula, namely,
$$\cos \alpha \cos \beta = \frac{1}{2}[\cos (\alpha + \beta) + \cos (\alpha - \beta)].$$

> **Additional hint** Taking $\alpha := \frac{7 \theta}{2}$ and $\beta := \frac{\theta}{2}$ and rearranging gives $$\cos 4\theta + \cos 3 \theta = 2 \cos \frac{7 \theta}{2} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}.$$